# Calculating runtime of 2^N functions

Tags: algorithm

For a homework assignment, I've been asked to calculate the runtime of various algorithms.  The part that is stumping me is the 2^N, because the size of N is so large.

Assuming a 2^N algorithm with a a data size N=1000 takes 5 seconds to execute, calculate the runtime for data sizes {2000, 3000, 10000}

Now, 2^2000/2^1000 = 2^1000 by the property of exponent division.  The result is 5.071509e+301 seconds to execute on a data set of 2000 items.

How can I give a number for the next two sizes?  2^2000 and 2^9000 both return infinity in any calculator that I use.  The professors hint is that 2^10 is approximate to 10^3, which means that 1024 is approximate to 1000.

Comment: 2 to the 2000 divided by 2 to to the 2000 is equal to 2 to the 2000 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of time complexity is f(N) = c * 2<sup>N</sup>.

Since f(1000) = 5, we can solve for c = 5 / 2<sup>1000</sup>.

So f(N) = 5 * 2<sup>N - 1000</sup>, and f(k * 1000) = 5 * 2<sup>(k - 1)*1000</sup>.

The blockade seems to be with calculating 2<sup>n</sup>, so I will guide you on this.

I will take one of your example to demonstrate the method:

2<sup>1000</sup> = 2<sup>10 * 100</sup> = (2<sup>10</sup>)<sup>100</sup> ≈ (10<sup>3</sup>)<sup>100</sup> = 10<sup>3 * 100</sup> = 10<sup>300</sup> = 1e300

That is using your teacher's hint, another way to calculate the number more accurately is:

2<sup>1000</sup> = 10<sup>1000 * log<sub>10</sub>2</sup> = 10<sup>301.03</sup> = 10<sup>0.03</sup> * 10<sup>301</sup> = 1.0715e301

(As you can see, the more accurate method will be 10.7 times more than the result from the approximate method)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you have not tried WolframAlpha:

```
2^9000 = 1861919823602446870051646947443265806218680881620164150161309755333181392347475969737916885903925979688282376725245050928552019850699830936678289110574564545897808148390669479768088103164174862614314896361751492419355200744919106773071079582599147802839706215610874713577461171484389014531465527630202236883843662826326484204605969450292309212479576754101484210438029392847117393209646612418243468945316443055403112189769994194382253211069075682210324665380367163398351260390065146550963353638226230571087153090476005831034463871223599543367440127371321307935600294235235555686651194174520755709233252147269712646152398661272615394330256766919854213808655136454478279520538925315159120689449046824765276993871084725126289174642261134186532952389529497451225294280309592333118547431857834022107299493307642886550035108349812538868548204110949267007844894921304724439232280030484032946555862021618822463975371563390466476093942333021906014621095132521668771544547398222309222385454252810109269995041305909748903485123565191403462125774254093965366838199092942669763234497755795922782368415391408328615941087687168142703569478330639528167193433105543630476588701348505543567751790789117717660152741734303989082897740369036292716627460893145378475903236426283709902853825833522685221030263417298462852391838147572583018386475574242223720125609852369550108535609838296845885540331405153336504029657425852682616998765068978970510668576704757343969900471616618487531217423608126248306049345412199702325217046285213249285846153975313978242675003402962824121160875928608618335006217051712260195130737083017631349816669929159176667868417353866905513835554999462637481342721400975639504482716709384155856026263304270260886740810287158032302083388891446551907198669473320114371718138443660594911466234734942910722449045244457975320043694169261701681656148362205170532994281152576853709669767416127252738437485793910219846836498268031157261792859230067295449184914230926461991700842371010236588596679342492743911615365711320743215987995901101163306076544568626531198809370907612331483471833845958618077480217892890533116603350040147116218227928732817945323636422047507156427135297222275812678187736036773320854938458989641651199078792658709405149957007882875374868180442468709128120647047303125901843060904208622152998500617510802742432155144605848971282208131749602408191808406410632175265171306237793956570406435402345476628467209068729893134433124291187516075267594298323098487990166243403468912628117388443154921474663149036640983804471509564893426039130480070632369458141251485052936042164865777219873983089572387511794739572152294019631222145910901210840561445507713655658889336373566800391206925212386456974315749376
```

As for the hint:

2<sup>9000</sup> = (2<sup>10</sup>)<sup>900</sup> ≈ (10<sup>3</sup>)<sup>900</sup> = 10<sup>2700</sup>

Considering that you know the runtime for 2<sup>1000</sup>, it's easy to determine the runtime for 2<sup>10000</sup> without WolframAlpha:

2<sup>1000</sup> => 5s
2<sup>10000</sup> = 2<sup>1000</sup>*2<sup>9000</sup> => 5*2<sup>9000</sup>s

Comment: I just got into the trap of 5^(2000/1000) just now... (I'm not the downvoter) Check my answer for the reason why it is not like that.